# SQLite does not cast to integer

Tags: string, sqlite, casting, integer, type-conversion

I've created the following select and calculate the "missing" value

```
 select strftime('%d.%m. %H:%M', O_LROU_DEPARTDATE) || ' - ' || O_LROU_IDENT as Ident,  
        O_LROU_CSLCNTPICKED as 'done',
        CAST((O_LROU_CSLCNT - O_LROU_CSLCNTPICKED) as integer) as 'missing'

   from RAW_OM36     

 where (O_LROU_CSLCNT - O_LROU_CSLCNTPICKED) > 0
```

But the missing value is still a text and not a integer. 
[Here a picture! What's going wrong?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c86Ss.png)

Comment: Add the column `typeof(CAST(O_LROU_CSLCNT - O_LROU_CSLCNTPICKED as integer))` to the SELECT clause. Does it also show "text"?

Comment: It's an integer value! That's crazy.

But the DataTable of the SQLiteDataAdapter in C# does also use string instead of integer for that column

Comment: This seems to be a problem with the DataTable.

Comment: Not necessarily, because as you can see on the screenshot, the SQLLiteStudio Version 3.1.1. has the same problem

Comment: Probably it uses DataTable, too? Anyway, the database returns an integer value; apparently, that SQLiteDataAdapter does not handle types correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have just had the same problem.

It is not clear from your picture how many records are selected. My driver determines the datatype from the first record.  If the value in the first record is null then the driver interprets the column as string (32767).  If the first record is a valid integer then the column is interpreted as integer.

A possible solution is to change
CAST((O_LROU_CSLCNT - O_LROU_CSLCNTPICKED) as integer)
to 
IFNULL(O_LROU_CSLCNT - O_LROU_CSLCNTPICKED), 0)
accepting that changing nulls to zeros might not be acceptable to you application.